# How to show $|\partial_x^n\partial_u^k p(u,x)| \leq Cu^{-|n|/2-k}p(cu,x)$; $p(u,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi u)^{q/2}}e^{-|x|^2/(4u)}$ is the normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, inequality, partial-derivative

Let $p(u,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi u)^{q/2}}e^{-|x|^2/(4u)},u>0,x \in \mathbb{R}^q.$

1. Prove that for $r\geq 0,c>1$ there exists $C>0$ (depending on $r,c$) such that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^q,u>0,\frac{|x|^{2r}}{u^r}p(u,x) \leq Cp(cu,x).$$
2. Deduce that for $n \in \mathbb{N}^q,k \in \mathbb{N},$ there exists $C'>0$ such that $|\partial_x^n\partial_u^k p(u,x)| \leq C' u^{-|n|/2-k}p(cu,x)$ where $\partial^n_x=\partial x_1^{n_1}...\partial x_q^{n_q}$

Attempt:

1. We have $\frac{|x|^{2}}{4ur}(1-\frac{1}{c}) \leq e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4ur}(1-1/c)}$ and we choose $C=c^{q/2} 4^r(r+1)^r/(1-1/c)^r$

How to deduce 2 (for simplicity we can take $q=1)$? *Is it possible to prove the inequality using induction*? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to prove the inequality directly with induction. This is because you cannot differentiate an inequality; $f\le g$ does not imply that $f' \le g'$.
Morally, you need to induct on something which you can differentiate.

In my earlier answer I provided the following hint:

> use induction to show that $\partial_x^n\partial_u^k p(u,x) = \sum_{i,j} x^{a_i} u^{b_j} p(u,x)$ for some appropriate powers $a_i,b_j$
> then apply 1.

I got the reply "For 2 it seems there is a lot of work to do considering it to be deduced from 1". This Answer hopefully shows that this isn’t really the case, especially in the age of <strike>chatGPT</strike> WolframAlpha. Checking small cases like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+%281%2F%284+pi+u%29%5E%7Br%2F2%7D%29+exp%28-x%5E2%2F%284u%29%29), not to mention being given the wanted result, we can refine our conjecture to

> For each $\alpha\in \mathbb N^q,k\in\mathbb N$, the expression $\partial_x^\alpha \partial_u^k p(u,x)$ can be written as a sum of finitely many (depending on $q,k,\alpha$) terms of the form $x^{\beta}u^{-|\beta|/2-|\alpha|/2-k} p(u,x)$

Which clearly implies the required result by absorbing the $\beta$ terms using part 1.

We induct in $|\alpha|+k$. The base case is trivial. If we inductively differentiate in $x_i$ where $\beta_i\neq0$ we get

$$(C_1x^{\beta-e_i}u^{-|\beta|/2-|\alpha|/2-k}+ C_2 x^{\beta+e_i} u^{-|\beta|/2-|\alpha|/2-1-k}) p(u,x)$$

which are terms of the correct form

$$x^{\beta’}u^{-|\beta’|/2-(|\alpha|+1)/2-k} p(u,x)$$

with $\beta’=\beta-e_i$ and $\beta’=\beta+e_i$ respectively. The case $\beta_i=0$ is simpler, and differentiating in $u$ instead presents no new difficulties: we get in this case
$$(C_3 x^{\beta}u^{-|\beta|/2-|\alpha|/2-(k+1)} + C_4|x|^2x^{\beta}u^{-|\beta|/2-1-|\alpha|/2-(k+1)}) p(u,x).$$
These are terms of the form
$$x^{\beta''}u^{-|\beta''|/2-|\alpha|/2-(k+1)} p(u,x)$$
with $\beta''=\beta$ or $\beta'' = \beta+2e_i$ with $i=1,\dots,q$, as needed.  So the proof is completed.

Answer (score 0):

For 1:$$\frac{|x|^{2r}}{u^r} p(u,x)=\frac{|x|^{2r}}{u^r}\frac{1}{(4\pi u)^{q/2}}e^{-|x|^2/(4u)}, \qquad  p(cu,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi u)^{q/2}c^{q/2}}e^{-|x|^2/(4cu)}, $$

so we are being asked to show that there exists $C=C(r,c,q)$ where
$$ \frac{|x|^{2r}}{u^r} \le \frac C{c^{q/2}}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4u}(\frac1c-1)}$$

Note $1/c-1<0$ so for $r=0$ we can just take $C=c^{q/2}.$

For $r$ a positive integer we have for $A>0,X\ge0$ that  $e^{AX} \ge A^rX^r/r!$. Applying this with $A = -(1/c-1)/4$ and $X=|x|^2/u$ we get
$e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4u}(\frac1c-1)}\ge \big(\frac{1-1/c}4\big)^r \frac{|x|^{2r}}{r!u^r}$ so we can take $$C = \frac{c^{q/2}r!}{\big(\frac{1-1/c}4\big)^r}$$

This implies estimates for all $r\ge0$ by interpolating which I will leave to you.

Idea for 2: use induction to show that $\partial_x^n\partial_u^k p(u,x) = \sum_{i,j} x^{a_i} u^{b_j} p(u,x)$ for some appropriate powers $a_i,b_j$
then apply 1.

Comment: There was an error I meant to take $C=c^{q/2} 4^r(r+1)^r/(1-1/c)^r$ using $x\leq e^x,$

Comment: We can consider 2 cases $r=0$ and $r>0$

Comment: @mathex if you want, but the constant is a little bit worse than the one I got (see above)

Comment: For 2 it seems there is a lot of work to do considering it to be deduced from 1

Comment: @mathex you're more than welcome to come up with a quicker solution :)